# Nested values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the object:

```
var votes = {
  "Alex": {president: "Bob"},
  "Bob": {president: "Mary"},
  "Cindy": {president: "Cindy"},
  "Devin": {president: "Louise"},
  "Ernest": {president: "Fred"},
  "Fred": {president: "Louise"},
  "Gail": {president: "Fred"},
  "Hermann": {president: "Ivy"},
  "Ivy": {president: "Louise"},
  "John": {president: "Louise"},
  "Kerry": {president: "Fred"},
  "Louise": {president: "Nate"},
}
```

How would I go about counting all the votes for President? Specifically, how can I show that "Louis" had the most votes?

The only thing I have so far is being about to see who voted for who with:

```
for (i in votes)
{
     console.log(votes[i].president);
};
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I was able to use what is stated below and got it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

```
var president = [];

for(k in votes) {
    president.push(votes[k]['president']);
}
```

After this, you need to count the occurrence of each element in the 
`president` array.

Answer (score 3):

I worked this out. A little haphazard, but gives correct answer.

```
var votes = {
 "Alex": {president: "Bob"},
 "Bob": {president: "Mary"},
 "Cindy": {president: "Cindy"},
 "Devin": {president: "Louise"},
 "Ernest": {president: "Fred"},
 "Fred": {president: "Louise"},
 "Gail": {president: "Fred"},
 "Hermann": {president: "Ivy"},
 "Ivy": {president: "Louise"},
 "John": {president: "Louise"},
 "Kerry": {president: "Fred"},
 "Louise": {president: "Nate"}
  }
  var holder = {};
  var largest = 'Alex';
  for( var i in votes){
    var num = holder[votes[i].president] || 0;
    holder[votes[i].president] = 1 + num;
        if(holder[votes[largest].president] < holder[votes[i].president]){
            largest = votes[i].president;
        }
  }

  console.log(largest); // louise
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make a list of every president and count in an array. As karthikr already mentioned in a comment

```
var presidents = {},
    president;
for(person in votes)
{
    president = votes[person].president;
    if (! (president in presidents))
        presidents[president] = [];
    presidents[president].push(person);
}
```

that will put every president in a list (presidents) with the people that voted for him.

to get the president with the highest ammount of votes is nothing more than iterating through the array and doing a check if this president has more votes than the current voted highest president.

```
var highest = false;
for(president in presidents)
{
    if (! highest || presidents[president].length > presidents[highest].length)
        highest = president;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a good start, now you'll have to code the loop to count the votes. Something like:

```
scores = {}; //will hold the names and votes.
for (i in votes)
{
     var votedfor = votes[i].president; // get who was voted for
     if(scores[votefor]) scores[votefor]++; //if we have the name in our scores, add 1
     else scores[votefor] = 1; //if we don't - set his(or her) score to 1 (which also add to scores).
};
```

Scores then holds {"Bob" : 1, "Fred" : 2, "Mary" : 1, "Louise" : 3 .... etc }
Notice that it's **unordered**.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
results = {}
for (voter in votes) {
    choice = votes[voter].president;
    if (!results[choice]) {
        results[choice] = 1 
    } else {
        results[choice]++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to do a map reduce using a framework like Backbone.js

Assuming you're doing this with no frameworks, you already have how to get who each person voted for.  Why not store the totals in an array?

```
var voteTotals = [];
for (i in votes)
{
     // get who the current vote was for
     var currentVote = votes[i].president;
     // initialize to 0 votes if no votes found for this person yet
     if (!(currentVote in voteTotals)) voteTotals[currentVote] = 0;
     voteTotals[currentVote]++;
};

for (i in voteTotals)
{
    console.log(i + ": " + voteTotals[i]);
};
```

Then, you should be able to sort and get the values as needed!